Why can't C++ overload resolution deduced nested template types?
This purported duplicate explains the mechanism of why this isn't allowed and shows a corner case where it can't work, but fails to address the question of why C++ refuses to allow it in the cases where it could work.
tl;dr; I know that C++ can't do this and I know how to work around it via ADL and am not asking about that. What I don't know is why the language design chose to (or was forced to) disallow this.

The longer version:
The following code works in all but the last case:
template <class T>
struct A { struct R {}; };

template <>
struct A<double> { using R = int; };

void Fn(int);

template <class T>
void Fn(typename A<T>::R v);

////////////////////////////////

void Test() {
    A<double>::R d;
    A<int>::R v;

    Fn(0);  // Works; calls Fn(int)
    Fn(d);  // Wroks; calls Fn(int)
    Fn(v);  // Fails; expected to call Fn<int>(A<int>::R)
}

It fails because the language is unable to infer template argument T for the template overload of Fn in order to make typename A<T>::R into A<int>::R. For a human, in this case, it's plainly clear that T should be int, but the rules of C++ don't allow that inference to be made.
My actual question:
What motivated or forced the designer of C++ to impose that restriction?
I suspect that the answer is that "guessing" that a class template will have a nested type before actually resolving it is technically or philosophically problematic, or that implementing that logic in existing compilers was architecturally prohibitive. That said, only the first of those is a fundamental problem and I'm not actually seeing why any of those are necessarily true, and that suggests I'm missing something interesting.

BTW: unless Bjarne Stroustrup or someone who was on the C++ standards committee in the 90's sees this, it's likely the best answer I'll get is well informed speculation.

P.S.
Several people have pointed out that where A<R>::S is provided as a using alias (particularly by explicit specialization) the resulting proper/fully-resolved type may not mention A<> at all.

Though a valid point, that's not the situation I'm asking about.
That's only relevant under the assumption that types and type aliases must be treated indistinguishably during type deduction. That may be a choice that the standards committee made, but it's a choice rather than something forced on them.
Even under the current situation and rules, explicit specialization and type aliases can result some  bazaar and unexpected results in like this:

template<int I> struct Int;
template<> struct Int<0> { using T = int; };
template<> struct Int<1> { using T = long; };

template<int I>
struct C {
    using T = typename Int<I % 2>::T;

    static int Mine();
    friend int Get(T) { return C::Mine(); }
};

void Test() {
    C<0> c0; // Ok
    C<1> c1; // This doesn't break anything.
    C<2> c2; // Delete this and things work.
    /*
    error: redefinition of 'int Get(C<2>::T)'
    note: 'int Get(C<0>::T)' previously declared here
    */
}


Finding T from typename A<T>::R is a hard inverse problem. The compiler would have to go through all the possible partial specializations of A<T> to find what matches T, even specializations not seen so far (and at the end there could be several). Partial specialization is simultaneously powerful and limiting for certain expected pattern matching behaviors. This is separate from ADL as far as I know, which is controversial in a different sense.

The claimed duplicate doesn't answer my question because it only shows a case where deduction has to fail because there is ambiguity, but it doesn't seem to say anything about the cases (like the one in the question) where these is no ambiguity.

@alfC IIRC asking for a specialization of a template without all (relevant) partial/full specializations already being seen is already UB and there are many cases where it's allowed. -- Simply resolving the template name and (assuming it the same as the augments value template) grabbing the template argument from the argument type before continuing with RAII rules would seem to work.

you expect a fixed 1:1 relation where there is none. Suppose a specialization template <> struct A<double> { using R = A<int>::R; }; Now Fn(v); could call Fn<double> as well. Its not just an arbitrary restriction made up by c++

Try template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, typename A<int>::R>::value, int>::type = 0> void Fn(T v) { /*...*/ } that should help clarify why then templating typename U instead of int would be a challenging (expensive, in terms of compilation times) problem to solve.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai But in that case the compiler will never be asked to resolve a call to Fn(A<double>::R) but rather a call to Fn(A<int>::R) (because the first is not even a type, but rather an alias for the second) which can still be resolved the same way I'm suggesting. -- The closest you have provided to a reason is the unstated implication of "it would confuse users", which to be fair is a valid point, just not a hard block.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai .... that said Calling Fn<double>(A<double>::R{}) vs Fn(A<double>::R{}) will get potentially unexpected results, but would still be well defined.

The implementtion would need to check every specialization of A in order to resolve Fn. In case of several parameters, it would need to check every combination of specializations of all parameters. This is simply too much to ask.

"will get potentially unexpected results, but would still be well defined" That's quite enough to never allow anything like that in the standard.

@n.m.couldbeanAI See edit: As long as A<T>::S is a actual type and not an alias, only one instantiation of A<> needs to be inspected and it can be extracted directly from the type of the argument. The case where A<T>::S is an alias is already allowed. -- As for  "unexpected results", that ship has long since sailed. For example take a look at literally every UB in C++.

@Eljay I don't see a meaningful connection. That template would be checked for argument types that are not a class nested inside of A<T>. The behavior I'm contemplating would not trigger if, for example, A<int>::S was a using because the actual type of the argument would resolve to something that doesn't mention A<>.

template<typename T> void Fn(std::is_class<T>::type v); called as Fn(std::true_type{}). What is T? Even better: template<unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned n> struct Fermat { using type = std::conditional<(n > 2) && pow(a,n) + pow(b,n) == pow(c,n), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type; }; template<unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned n> void Fn(Fermat<a,b,n>::type); and now you call Fn(std::true_type{}). Hooray, the compiler has to prove Fermat's Last Theorem!

So far I see more confusion and limitations than usefulness. Is there a compelling use case?

overload resolution makes no difference for type aliases. I understood the question "could it be done in c++" as "could it be done without changing large parts of the language as it is?" ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah! There is the confusion. I never asked "could it be done in c++" (I already knew the answer to that is almost certainly yes) but rather the related but distinctly different "what exactly drove the choice to not do it in c++?" -- The standards committee choosing to consider it important to make type aliases transparent, in both directions, WRT template definitions and type deduction would be a potential answer (but even then there is already weirdness when those alias turn out to be non-unique, see edit.).

@RaymondChen At first I thought you had forgotten the ::type in your example making them trivially moot :0), but I guess I'll have to stick with the "I'm specifically excluding from consideration the case where the declared type is an alias the refers outside of the template that declares it." (I'll have to think some on the case where it's an alias within the template).

@n.m.couldbeanAI For a compelling uses case: "write operator<<(ostream, A<T>::S) without making it a friend or member function of either A<T> or A<T>::S".

@BCS You can use the same counterexample with an alias type to locally-defined true_type and false_type. Even if you could narrow it to specific cases that work, is it worth adding even more complexity to template deduction to accommodate this one case?

@RaymondChen actually, I don't think that would work. If true_type is a nested inside Fermat than you would first have to fix a, b and n before the overload would even be considered, at that point, all you have is a test for a claimed counterexample. -- Too much complexity is a valid, if unsatisfying, answer.

@BCS you are implicitly making using a second class citizen. In 463035818_is_not_an_ai 's example A<int>::R and A<double>::R are both names for the same type. That's how names work in C++

@Caleth that's not a new issue. Non template overloads already treat an overload defined via a using as taking the aliased type. (Some compilers mention the using in diagnostic messages for the users benefit, but that's not the language it self.)  Furthermore, your comment doesn't address the question of why that choice was made.

@BCS No, a using declaration gives a type another name. Or it's first name, if you using a type with no name, e.g. struct {} foo; using foo_t = decltype(foo);. To say that the name given at the point of declaration is the "main name" would involve defining the concept of "main name", it's probably a choice by absence

I wouldn't call redefinition of 'int Get(C<2>::T)' bizarre. Defining a friend function is still defining a function, you can't do that multiple times.

@Caleth check out the other link for the bizarre stuff. That case is just unexpected, until you see what's going on, which could be arbitrarily far away. The compiler trying to treat using's as if they are proper types just makes the error message more confusing. (Note, clang gives a message without types at all, which at least is less misleading.)

@BCS They are proper types. The other link is unrelated to aliases, stateful metaprogramming is a hole in the standard that the committee haven't figured out a patch for.

@Caleth a using alias is not what I'm referring to when I use the phrase "proper type", so I might be miss using that phrase. Regardless, the distinction between a using alias and "the thing I'm referring to" is useful in that the things I'm referring to are the only types that actually show up in the compiled code (e.g. in mangled names or that participate in overload resolution) as opposed to using's which are transplant and replaced by the thing they alias before those steps.

@BCS you've got it backwards. "types that actually show up in the compiled code" is looking at implementation details. The types are an abstract thing, with some number of names attached to them in source. That one name comes from the point of definition isn't material to the fact that all the names for a type equally denote the type.

@Caleth citation required. I'm reasonably sure you are wrong and, unless you can cite where the official standard document explicitly says otherwise, you will not persuade me otherwise. Even saying "they are treated equivalently" would be an acknowledgment that they are not in fact the same.

@Caleth: Aliases are complicated.  Sometimes they are transparent, even for CTAD, but they can be template template arguments in their own right, and they can be distinguished from the original via the redeclaration rules.

In the general case, as discussed in the comments, it’s impossible to invert the metafunction T → typename A<T>::R.  In the case where there really is a nested type with that name, certainly it could be deduced; presumably that case was considered too narrow to be motivating, especially if users might not understand the limitations and brittleness of the feature.
When a paper proposing to support the feasible case was presented, the feeling of the committee was that it would be a breaking change, in the somewhat unusual sense that it would allow deduction (and its associated powers of introspection) to apply to types previously insulated from such analysis.  People didn’t want to have to rename their nested types (breaking ABI even given type aliases under the old names for source compatibility) to prevent a change in semantics, and the ability to do things like customize for a member of any specialization of a class template (via overloads or partial specializations) wasn’t considered compelling.

Do you have a link for the stuff you refer to following "the feeling of the committee"? I'll take you at your word that it happened, but I'd be interested in the original discussion. (Maybe I've been watching to much CourtTV: you comments makes me want to say "objection; hearsay".)

@BCS: While the committee routinely publishes terse summaries of its deliberations now, it didn’t then, and the minutes aren’t public.  That said, it’s not hearsay if I’m testifying about statements made in my presence so long as I’m not claiming it to be evidence of the factuality of those statements!

Oh, but I'm more wondering at the committee's motive for making that choice, not what they said it is. (Nitpicking, I know. ;0)
